# Java based OSM tile rendering in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, openstreetmap

Does anyone know of a JavaFX component which can render tile-based maps from e.g. OpenStreetMap directly from Java - i.e. not using the WebEngine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gluon has Maps, an open source project that you can find [here](https://github.com/gluonhq/maps).

It uses OpenStreetMap, and it has a JavaFX control: the `MapView`.

See a quick demo [here](https://github.com/gluonhq/maps/blob/master/src/main/java/com/gluonhq/maps/demo/DemoMap.java).

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

    MapView view = new MapView();
    view.setCenter(new MapPoint(50, 0));
    view.setZoom(5); 
    Scene scene = new Scene(view, 600, 350);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

[image: MapView]

Comment: Indeed. Thank you very much.