# How to show Open Street Maps in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx, openstreetmap

Is there a way to add OSM to JavaFX app, in a way to be able to interact with that map (i.e. Add polygons, get coordinates of clicked location)?

Comment: I am guessing `WebView`.

Comment: @Sedrick does it allow to interact with the map and pass i.e. coordinates from map to ListView element?

Comment: Yes, but you need to use JavaScript to do the interop. Alternatively you can try and use a `SwingNode` together with [JOSM](https://josm.openstreetmap.de/).

Comment: If it is not necessary OSM ,you can use GMaps API for JavaFX.It helps you to interact with google map.http://rterp.github.io/GMapsFX/

Comment: @MenaiAlaEddine in my project I have to use OSM.

Comment: See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43737404/java-based-osm-tile-rendering-in-javafx/43737656#43737656) about Gluon Maps. It uses OSM, and you can interact with it, and add any JavaFX based overlay.

Comment: java wrapper for mapbox, osp and google map: https://github.com/makbn/java_leaflet

Answer (score 4):

After trying suggestion from other answers, I found out that the solution, which fits me best is: https://www.sothawo.com/projects/mapjfx/

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this problem easily using my open-source project [Java Leaflet](https://github.com/makbn/java_leaflet). This project provides a set of utilities that simplify the task you're trying to accomplish.

```
final JLMapView map = JLMapView
    .builder()
    .mapType(JLProperties.MapType.DARK)
    .accessToken(ACCESS_TOKEN)
    .startCoordinate(JLLatLng.builder()
            .lat(43.54)
            .lng(22.54)
            .build())
    .build();
```

This library should simplify the task and save you time. If you have any questions or encounter any issues, feel free to create an issue on the GitHub repository, and I'll be happy to assist you.